# How are dies, diodes, chips and the like separated from each other on a wafer?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I would like to know how the single dies on a wafer are (electrically) separated from each other. Are they even?

[image: img1]

More precisely, as the wafer themselves are held on a so-called susceptor (basically just a plate to put the wafers on to be heated) and these susceptors are made out of graphite or silicon carbid, I would assume there must be an electric connection across the entire susceptor/wafer. So, I'd think this is a potential risk for damages?

[image: img2]

Comment: The substrate is common. Die are not interconnected.

Comment: Does this mean, even though the susceptor below it, could provide a current, the dies would not be affected accordingly?

Comment: The bigger issue in my fab experience is plasma processes where current can be induced in device structures. Small current in a thick substrate is not an issue.

Comment: Note that this question is off topic here, it might be better asked at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: @Ruslan The last time I asked something on Electrical Engineering (why car batteries are connected as they are) I got punished that it is not about Electrical Engineering and rather about Engineering. And since semiconductor physics, involving production of wafers and so on, was/is a big department at our physics institute, I was quite sure that this here would be the right channel..      but it seems, a very lot of physicists at my former university are no physicists but engineers. Have to tell them, so they can adjust their future careers.

Comment: Well, that question was closed for being not "about electronics design". This one _is_ about electronics design: desigining the way ICs are produced _is_ design. There've been some questions on EE, similar to this one in spirit: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/522214, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/51441, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/473817, and these haven't been closed.

Comment: Wafer production is not electronics design. You'll use a wafer to produce electronics on it but the wafer itself is no electronic component. On EE there is even another, older, and quite similar question about how a car battery has to be connected. It hasn't been closed, so, for me, it's just random/arbitrary how the sites handle the questions. Despite that, as I said, wafer production is mainly done in (solid state) physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wafer is made of a substrate material, which is common to all of the die.  On top of the substrate, the electrical structures are added by depositing small amounts of appropriate material (conductor, semiconductor, etc.) in successive layers. The layout of the individual die on the wafer includes consideration that they will be separated enough on the substrate that any imprecision in the deposition of layers will not electrically connect the different die on the wafer.

(Likewise, for the individual die, part of the design process for each die considers whether the structures on the die can be reliably deposited within the precision of the manufacturing technique to be used.)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not that much into this topic and currently, I'm mainly focusing on the CVD. Now I wonder, how the electronic structures are put on the wafers so precisely that they do not overlap and the like? This can't be done via CVD..? I guess the CVD is only for the substrate?

Comment: That's a different question completely. You should ask it as such because it's more than a comment's worth of material.

Comment: Which question exactly would that be? :)

Comment: @Ben don't forget about photolithography, which can protect the areas you don't want exposed to CVD.

Comment: @Ben CVD, like most thin film deposition processes, deposits a blanket of material across the entire substrate. It is not a process where you get to pick and choose where the material goes. (Okay, yes, there are some selective deposition processes, but that requires surface prep to get what you want)

Comment: Thank you! Just to ensure (and to have a basis for my own research): The layer, deposited by the CVD, is just the very first layer and the electronic structures/layers are added afterwards (and probably also somewhere else in another machine)?

Comment: @Ben no, other layers like metallization and oxide can also be deposited by CVD.

Comment: Well, ok, but they do not form any further function among the wafer? Or in other words: They all cover the entire wafer and are "just" a basis for further deposits and the like (somewhere else)?